# Is a map containing addresses of out-of-scope objects undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

If I have a map of object addresses to some other type e.g. string:

```
std::map<unsigned long, std::string> index;
//       ^^^ This is a number representing address of an object
//       that may go out of scope while the map is still alive.
```

Is <strike>pushing to it objects</strike> using addresses to objects that may go out of scope before the map, undefined behavior? Note that **I'm only reading the address**, and not modifying the addressed object through the map.

Comment: your map does not contain adresses but objects.

Comment: Note that `long` is not guaranteed to be big enough to contain a pointer. Use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`

Comment: I'm not totally sure on what you mean. If the `long` is typecast to a pointer that points to something out of scope, that in of itself is not ub. But obviously if you explicitly dereference and read/write to the object, it is ub. If you're using a raw pointer, then the story is a bit different, it is ub to read a pointer to something that has been free'd.

Comment: the question is unclear. Are you storing adresses in the `unsigned long`? or did you forget a `*` on `string` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "pushing to an object"? Could you create a simple complete exemplary code?

Comment: What is `string`?

Comment: Scope is irrelevant. Lifetime is the issue here. Objects do not even have scope. Identifiers do.

Comment: This question suffers for [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). So my question is: Why you need this?

Comment: @MarekR oh I don't need this, I want to make sure that it doesn't create UB. Seen it in legacy code and pondering whether to weed it out or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `string` is `std::string`, it is not an address. `unsigned long` is not an address either.

In case you converted some pointer values to `unsigned long` and use that `unsigned long` as key in the map there is not problem with reading those integers. They have no implicit relation to the original pointers.

Comment: Crystal clear thanks. The `long` is the the address but as you say a new object is created that holds the address (number) of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is :

> Is pushing to it objects that may go out of scope before the map, undefined behavior?

My answer assume that by "pushing" you mean adding or inserting elements to the map. In the below code example we are adding objects(pairs) to the map which go out of inner scope but even then accessing the map is valid because the objects were copied into the map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<unsigned long, std::string> index;
    
    {//new scope started

    //create some objects to insert into the map inside this new scope
    std::pair<unsigned long, std::string> pair1(4, "String1");
    std::pair<unsigned long, std::string> pair2(5, "String2");
    std::pair<unsigned long, std::string> pair3(6, "String3");
    
    //add these objects into the map 
    index.insert(pair1);//pair1 is copied into the map so you dont have to worry about pair1 going out of scope
    index.insert(pair2);//pair2 is copied
    index.insert(pair3);//pair3 is copied as well
    
    }//pair1, pair2 and pair3 goes out of scope after this point
    
    std::cout<<index.at(4)<<std::endl;//this is ok because all the pair objects were copied into the map so you don't have to worry about them going out of scope 
    return 0;
}
```

So the objects(`std::pair`) are going out of scope after we insert them into the map. But we can still use the map because those `pair` were copied into the map. So it is fine to insert elements into the map that may go out of scope before the map.

Comment: this is a misuse of `std::make_pair`, because `"String1"` is not a string. Its not an error, but simply not using `make_pair` would be less contrived

Comment: I clarified my question a bit. I was asking a different thing

Answer (score 0):

> Is pushing to it objects that may go out of scope before the map, undefined behavior?

No.

Please note that (as other have mentioned) your map does not contain addresses to external object, but the *copies* of the objects (the copies will have their own lifetimes, unrelated to the original).

A map of pointers would be:

```
std::map<unsigned long, std::string*> index;
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. The key-`long` is the address (a copy of the address number) but as you say as long as I don't do anything weird with it (like try to retrieve an object from that address) it's ok